# Deploy MongoDB cluster, node, express, mongoose app on AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to deploy a Node.js web app which uses mongoose and express on AWS for a week now.

I'm new to AWS and am not the best networker, so please have patience with my lack of networking understanding.

So far I have used AWS's Quickstart Guide to launch a new VPC with mongoDB.
Found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/welcome.html

I verified that the mongo database was working by ssh'ing into the private mongo IP's through the NAT gateway (using the keypair). It appears to be working fine and I have a username and password for admin level of the mongodb setup.

I then launched an elastic beanstalk node.js application within this VPC (or at least I think it was in here - the security rules include the subnets of the mongodb), with a call in my code as follows:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<MongoUsername>:<MongoPassword>@test.amazonaws.com:27017/admin')
```

where admin is the database name.

When I try to launch this node.js instance though, it does not run.

I have, however, verified that the node.js app runs independently of the VPS by launching a completely separate elastic beanstalk instance. It runs my code fine (but obviously doesn't connect to a db so forms do not work.)

What am I missing here? Why can I not connect this cluster to my node app? I'm super confused and frustrated with the whole process and would really appreciate any advice. Thanks.

If you need any further info to help me debug this let me know.

Edit: To the person who wants this closed as too broad.. what extra information do you want? I specified in the question that im new at this and to tell me what else you need.. so I find this classification without any clarification pretty rude and unhelpful. Cheers

Comment: i worked in the past with MongoDB over AWS and I don't remember so many issue. Do you have any error code from your Nodejs instance?

Comment: thanks Daniele, probably a lot of the issue is that im a beginner and don't have a very good understanding of networking. Thanks for the response though

Answer (score 0):

So this issue here was that I was not applying the correct security rules to my elastic beanstalk instance and it was therefore not rendering to the Ip.

Thanks to those that tried to help, if anyone has a similar issue and needs a hand, feel free to message me.

Comment: Hi Ally, I am also new in AWS hosting and currently I have a Node.js app with Express and MongoDb to host in elastic beanstalk. I have no idea how to deploy and test APIs globally as I am doing it locally. What are the changes to be made on code . Can you help me out?

Comment: HI @WhoAmI sorry I haven't used mongoDB with AWS again, so I can't advise you. But I'm sure many other stackoverflow people could help! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response and time. I have implemented my project successfully. Thanks again.

Comment: Awseome, nice job WhoAmI!